# CSF blocks my IP trying to access Webmin

Tags: csf

I'm in no way a sysadmin, so bear with me a little.

I have a cloud server running Centos 5. I have Virtualmin/Webmin with a handful of sites running without issue. I also have CSF installed to stop persistent bot attacks.

I can access all my sites HTTP and HTTPS (without SSL) and they work fine.

When I attempt to access my Webmin's web interface

```
https://myhost.co.uk:10000
```

My browser hangs, eventually times out. I can no longer access any of my sites due to CSF adding my IP to the temp disallow list, here's the log entry:

```
*Port Scan* detected from 213.86.xxx.xxx (GB/United Kingdom/-). 16 hits in the last 187 seconds - *Blocked in csf* for 3600 secs
```

Once I unblock my IP and add it to the temp allow list, I can access the web UI login page.

**Any ideas why the initial request is being disallowed?**

Comment: Is port 10000 in your `TCP_IN` and `TCP_OUT` settings?

Comment: No - I just added them in and it seems to have fixed the issue. Feel free to answer this question and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear it, will do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSF will consider any hits to ports not whitelisted in `csf.cfg`'s `TCP_IN` setting to be a port scanning attempt.

Since 10000 is a legitimate port for you, add it to the list in `TCP_IN` and `TCP_OUT` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: If you do this, then anyone can access the Webmin login. We use approved IP addresses and using GLOBAL_DYNDNS in CSF, so we cannot allow port 10000, so in this case for us, this solution is not a solution. Its best to identify the reason for port scanning. We have many port scanning to one server, not our others, very strange.